# Crm field control order Javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I would like to change the order in which the fields in a form get checked.

The field Email should be checked before the field City. They are both obligatory.

I would also like that when the email address is invalid only one Popup is shown (by default I get two- one saying the email is invalid and one saying that the field cannot be null)

Is it possible to change the order of the checks and do the custom checks before the system ones?

Marco

Answer (score 1):

The only supported method of changing the order in which the fields get checked, is changing the order on the form.  I'm assuming that CRM just loops through it's collection of controls to perform the field validations.  You could attempt to dive into the CRM javascript and figure out a method to hijack it.

A supported way of handling it would be to make the fields not required (either via javascript on the OnLoad, or updating the entity definition itself), and then on the OnSave, writing your own field validation.  It's a lot of extra work, and you lose the little red asterisk showing the field is required, but you'd be able to evaluate them in the order you'd like (or display a single message with everything that's missing (why that isn't done by default in CRM I'll never know)), and be able to fix your email invalid / not null message.

Answer (score 1):

CRM does not loop through its collection of controls as specified in the answer above.

The validation of the fields(business required) on a CRM form happen in the order in which they were added to the form, irrespective of where they are placed in the form. So, as of now, the only way to change the order in which they are validated is to add them in the same order as you want them validated.

Answer (score 1):

So far.. I believe the only option to work around this is stated in this link.

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8f402463-23aa-4bc1-862b-4f4093a0cce8/required-fields-order-of-validation?forum=crmdevelopment

Basically you would need to use javascript. Have only one field as mandatory. On change of this field set the next field (in the correct order) to mandatory and so on.. hectic but only way.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you are pasting a link as an answer, please copy the content from the linked page so that in the future the information is still available.